# How to encrypt a Disk Image with Touch ID?

Tags: disk-utility, keychain, encryption, touch-id

I have a MacBook Pro 2017 with Touch bar, and therefore Touch ID.  I have tried to setup everything that I can to use Touch ID including login and [to authenticate the sudo command](http://osxdaily.com/2017/11/22/use-touch-id-sudo-mac/).

I create a lot of encrypted Disk Images using Disk Utility for security purposes. It get's quite annoying and repetitive to type in the same/different password every single time I want to mount a Disk Image. I was wondering if there was a way to encrypt a Disk Image using Touch ID.  If not, then maybe a workaround to use Touch ID to "fill in" the password (perhaps from Keychain) when mounting.

I do know you can save the password in Keychain, but then it does not prompt for authentication when mounting the image.